# Alternative for Guava's Charmatcher methods such as javaDigit()?

Tags: java, guava, deprecated

I've been using Guava's CharMatcher for a long time and it's worked great for everything.  Now I see that most of the methods in it are now deprecated in Guava 27.0.1

The documentation says "Deprecated. Many digits are supplementary characters; see the class documentation."  However, after reading the class documentation, I am still confused.  Most of the time when a method is deprecated, they tell you an alternative way to do things, however, this time, I feel like the documentation is basically saying "This class doesn't really work correctly, so don't use it".

What is the correct way, for example, to only retain the digits of a string?  Before I could simply do:

```
String inputString = "abc123def456";
String outputString = CharMatcher.javaDigit().retainFrom(inputString);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Javadoc for the method states:

> ```
> @deprecated Many digits are supplementary characters; see the class documentation.
> ```

That means that besides numbers from 0 to 9 -- which you normally use -- there can be other character matched.

In Guava there are two built-in methods for that: [`digit()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#digit--) and [`javaDigit()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.0-jre/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#line.190). The former matches "*[BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) digit according to [Unicode](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7Bdigit%7D)*" specs, the latter matches "*BMP digit according to [`Character#isDigit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit-int-)*". Each of them match weird characters like Devanagari or Fullwidth 
digits (I won't even link them ;)), which rarely is what users want and can be misleading.

That's why the preferred way (by Guava authors) is to be explicit (it's stated later in javadoc):

> If you only care to match ASCII digits, you can use [`CharMatcher#inRange('0', '9')`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#inRange-char-char-).

In your case simply use:

```
String outputString = CharMatcher.inRange('0', '9').retainFrom(inputString);
```

Comment: ok that makes sense.  I'll just make my own utility methods which call to an inRange()

Comment: I do think it's silly that they are deprecating javaDigit() because it is just delegating to Character.isDigit() which is good behavior, and well defined.

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution, since I needed one: replace the deprecated methods with [CharMatcher.forPredicate](https://guava.dev/releases/23.4-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#forPredicate-com.google.common.base.Predicate-), and pass in one of the character classification methods from [the Java Character class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html).

```java
CharMatcher.forPredicate(Character::isDigit).retainFrom(inputString)
```